# Regex to split a string except in double quotes and keep the delimiters

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

I have been sifting to very similar questions but I am still stumped. I need to split a string by any non alphanumeric character and keep the delimiters *except* for parts of the string in double quotes. Hence, for:

```
string = 'let a = 5 * (other) if x is "constant";'
```

```
re.split(pattern, "string")
```

should yield:

```
['let', 'a', '=', '5', '*', '(', 'other', '),' 'if', 'x' 'is', '"constant"', ';']
```

I am getting pretty close with:

```
re.split(r"(\W)", fragment)
```

(except for whitespace that I filter out separately) but I cannot manage the double quotes.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
s = 'let a = 5 * (other) if x is "constant";'
print( re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|\w+|[^\w\s]', s) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RvsNsV) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/axJb61/1).

*Details*:

- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - a char other than a word and whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.split(r'[ ]|(?<=[(])|(?=[);])', string)
```

- [ ] - split on space
- (?<=[(])  - split after '('
- (?=[);])  - split before ')' or before ';'

['let', 'a', '=', '5', '*', '(', 'other', ')', 'if', 'x', 'is', '"constant"', ';']